Call Compiled Function in Python
How can I call a function made with Compile in Python, Is it possible to just save it using LibraryGenerateand call the executable in Python latter?

I would recommend to use the numba Python package to compile your program directly in your Python session. numba is really easy to use and very efficient. And it would remove also the most of the overhead that would be needed to communicated between Python and Mathematica.

@HenrikSchumacher my problem is that the expressions are some big polynomials that are generated automatically, so writing it myself in python is not really an option.
